# how to send string from/To C++ (6.0) to C++ DLL?

Tags: c++, string, dll

When I send text to my DLL and receive it as `char*`, something strange happens; if the text is less than 13 characters or greater than 77 characters the text returned is rubbish!

Here is my code:-

//(1) DLL function:

```
char* __stdcall ApplyArabicMapping( char* input)
{
    // 1-Conver char* to string
    std::string inputString = input;

    // 2-Calling our function
    string encodedStr = Encoding::arabicHandling(inputString);

    // 3-Convert from String to char*
    char* returnStr = (char*)encodedStr.c_str();
    return (returnStr);
}
```

//(2) Calling from C++ console application:

```
char* inputStr = "Some text";

char* resutls = ApplyArabicMapping(inputStr);
```

Comment: Have you run it in a debugger and stepped through the code to see what happens?

Comment: Please provide some example code on how you send and recieve the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A dangling pointer is being returned as `encodedStr` is being destructed when `ApplyArabicMapping()` returns, resulting in **undefined behaviour**.

To correct, either return a `std::string` if possible or make a copy of the `char*` buffer using `new` and return it: the caller must `delete[]` this when no longer required:

```
char* returnStr = new char[encodedStr.length() + 1];
std::copy(encodedStr.begin(), encodedStr.end(), returnStr);
*(returnStr + encodedStr.length()) = 0; // null terminate.
```